# Integrating timeshift and google drive

Tags: backup, cloud, google-drive

My system is running Ubuntu 16.04. I have unlimited access to **google drive** and I want to backup my file and system state (something like **restore point** in windows) by using **timeshift**. I was wondering if someone suggests a suitable way or other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have these packages installed:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts
```

Now open your `gnome-control-center` and go to Online Accounts and add your google account. After setup you can go to the File Browser and navigate to your drive location then press CTRL+L to show the URL.

Now configure timeshift to store backups at this URL by setting the "Storage Path" in the timeshift config. There may be a bit of extra work needed to "map" between the GVFS mount URLs and the local paths if timeshift doesn't support the way google drive is mounted.

See http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/use-google-drive-ubuntu-16-04-linux-desktops